# Creating multiple Ajax buttons with a each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, button

I have two models : User and Product. One user has many owned_products, and a product belongs to an owner. The products have a `available:boolean`.

I want to make a list of owned_products that can be toggled from available to unavailable with a button. Here is what I did, using the [M. Hartl example](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=4.0#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax) :

**app/views/shared/_owned_products_list.html.erb**

```rb
<ol class="products">
  <% @owned_products.each do |product| %>
    <%= link_to(product.name, product) %>
    <%= render 'products/available_form', product: product %>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

**app/views/products/_available_form.html.erb**

```rb
<div id="available_button_<%=product.id%>">
 <% if product.available? %>
    <%= form_for(product, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.hidden_field :available, value: nil %></div>
      <%= f.submit t('product.available.undo'), class: "btn btn-small" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= form_for(product, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.hidden_field :available, value: true %></div>
      <%= f.submit t('product.available.do'), class: "btn btn-primary btn-small" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**app/controllers/products_controller.rb**

```rb
    .
    .
    .
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html do
          flash[:success] = t('flash.success.product.update')
          redirect_to @product
        end
        format.js
      end
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
    .
    .
    .
```

**app/views/products/update.js.erb**

```rb
$("#available_form_<%=@product.id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('available_button', product: @product)) %>")
```

But it doesn't work : The available button is not refreshed at all :

When I click on the available (or unavailable) button, nothing change. If I refresh the whole page, it toggles, regardless the number of clicks...

Do you know where I failed ?

**EDIT**

OK, I got it, it was a dumb fault : my available_form id was `available_button_<%=@product.id%>` and not `available_form_<%=@product.id%>`...

So here is the right one :

**app/views/products/update.js.erb**

```rb
$("#available_button_<%=@product.id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('available_button', product: @product)) %>")
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using rails with jquery and jquery_ujs, make it simple:

in app/views/shared/_owned_products_list.html.erb

```
<ol class="products">
  <% @owned_products.each do |product| %>
    <%= link_to product.name, product %>
    <%= link_to product.available ? 'turn off' : 'turn on', '#', :class => 'toggle-availability', :'data-id' => product.id %>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

in your js-script file:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});    

$(document).on('click', '.toggle-availability', function() {
   var el = $(this);
   var status = el.text();
   $.post('/products/toggle', { id: el.data('id') }, function() {
      el.text(status == 'turn off' ? 'turn on' : 'turn off');
   });
   return false;
});
```

in the controller file:

```
def toggle
  if request.xhr?
     product = Product.find(params[:id])
     # note here that you should also check the owner of the product
     product.available = product.available.nil? ? true : false
     product.save
  end
  render :nothing => true
end
```

and in your routes.rb add:

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    get :toggle
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you ! It will be helpful. But do you know why it doesn't work my way ?

Comment: Ok, first of all I don't see in your code any tag with #available_form_<%=@product.id%>, only available_button_<%=product.id%>